# How can I export a layer into .shp in qgis when it is not an option in the file types?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

I am really new to qgis and I do not know how to go about this. I just downloaded it yesterday.

Comment: Please post some screen shots of what you are doing and where you are running into difficulty.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Answer (score 5):

In the "Layers" window, left-side of the map view, you will see all layers in your map.

Right-click on the layer you want to export to ESRI Shapefile.

[image]

There is an option to Export the layer. Choose "**Export -> Save Features As**" and a new window will appear.

Under Format, choose the dropdown and select ESRI Shapefile. This will save the file as a ".shp" and all the additional files required by a shapefile.

[image]

You can then choose the location on your system to save this file.

Comment: Can you perform the above process while maintaining the symbology?